# How to copy the rest of lines of a file to another file

Tags: files, grep, cat, file-copy, file-transfer

I have the string `xyz` which is a line in `file1.txt`, I want to copy all the lines after `xyz` in `file1.txt` to a new file `file2.txt`. How can I achieve this?

I know about `cat` command. But how to specify the starting line?

Comment: Do you want to include that `xyz` line or exclude it from being copied ? Also, what happens if you have multiple lines matching `xyz` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using GNU sed

To copy all lines **after** `xyz`, try:

```
sed '0,/xyz/d' file1.txt >file2.txt
```

`1,/xyz/` specifies a range of lines starting with the first and ending with the first occurrence of a line matching `xyz`.  `d` tells sed to delete those lines.

**Note:** For BSD/MacOS sed, one can use `sed '1,/xyz/d' file1.txt >file2.txt` but this only works if the first appearance of `xyz` is in the second line or later.  (Hat tip: [kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda).)

Another approach,  as suggested by [don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti), should work for **all** sed:

```
{ printf %s\\n; cat file1.txt; } | sed '1,/xyz/d' >file2.txt
```

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file1.txt
a
b
xyz
c
d
```

Run our command:

```
$ sed '1,/xyz/d' file1.txt >file2.txt
$ cat file2.txt
c
d
```

#### Using awk

The same logic can used with awk:

```
awk 'NR==1,/xyz/{next} 1' file1.txt >file2.txt
```

`NR==1,/xyz/{next}` tells awk to skip over all lines from the first (`NR==1`) to the first line matching the regex `xyz`.  `1` tells awk to print any remaining lines.

Comment: @John1024 What `sed` are you using there?

Comment: @Kusalananda `sed --version` returns `(GNU sed) 4.4`.

Comment: Plz note that your answer first said: `sed '0,/xyz/d` then `sed '1,/xyz/d`. Whcih one is correct?

Comment: @user9371654 If you have GNU sed (Linux, Windows, etc), use `sed '0,/xyz/d`.  If you have BSD sed (default MacOS), then use `{ printf %s\\n; cat file1.txt; } | sed '1,/xyz/d' >file2.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

With `ed`:

```
ed -s file.txt <<< $'/xyz/+1,$w file2.txt'
```

This sends one (ranged) command to `ed`: from the line *after* (`+1`) the one containing `xyz` until the end of the file (`$`), `w`rite those lines to `file2.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

There is also csplit :

```
csplit -s file1.txt %xyz%1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -n '/xyz/,$p' file.txt > file2.txt
```

With `-n` we prevent `sed` to print every line. With `$` means end of file end `p` stands for print line. So `/xyz/$p` means: If a line matches `xyz` print it until the end of the file.

Comment: This would also print the line matching `xyz`, not from the line after.